# Django Admin's "view on site" points to example.com instead of my domain

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I added a `get_absolute_url` function to one of my models.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/foo/bar'
```

The admin site picks it up and adds a "view on site" link to the detail page for that object (when I put a real URL there instead of "/foo/bar").

The problem is instead of going to `http://localhost:8000/foo/bar`, it goes to `http://example.com/foo/bar`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Thom Wiggers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26947339) provides really eloquent solution to the problem

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to change [default site](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#ref-contrib-sites) domain value.

Comment: Thanks. It took me a while to figure out how to do that. It's an entry in the django_site table. I found and changed it by clicking on "Sites" in the admin.

Answer (score 6):

The funniest thing is that "example.com" appears in an obvious place. Yet, I was looking for in in an hour or so.

Just use your admin interface -> Sites -> ... there it is :)

Answer (score 4):

You can change this in /admin/sites if you have admin enabled.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, this is to do with the [default `sites` framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/sites/#how-django-uses-the-sites-framework).

If you're using [South](http://south.aeracode.org) for database migrations (probably a good 
idea in general), you can [use a data migration to avoid having to make this same database change everywhere you deploy your application](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/a-data-migration-for-every-django-project/), along the lines of

```
from south.v2 import DataMigration
from django.conf import settings

class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        Site = orm['sites.Site']
        site = Site.objects.get(id=settings.SITE_ID)
        site.domain = 'yoursite.com'
        site.name = 'yoursite'
        site.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on newer versions of django. the data migration is like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations

def change_site_name(apps, schema_editor):
    Site = apps.get_model('sites', 'Site')
    site = Site.objects.get(id=settings.SITE_ID)
    site.domain = 'yourdomain.com'
    site.name = 'Your Site'
    site.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(change_site_name),
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have edited a Site instance thought the admin, you need to restart your web server for the change to take effect. I guess this must mean that the database is only read when the web server first starts.