# How can I store 3rd party package migrations in a Django project?

Tags: django, django-migrations, feincms

I'm using the `page` module in `feincms` and when I add extensions to my settings I'd like to be able to store the migrations in my git repo.

There is some [documentation on migrations in `FeinCMS`](http://feincms-django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrations.html), but it looks incomplete, and I'm not able to get this working.

The file structure I have is:

```
- app
  - feincms_
    - migrate
      - __init__.py
    ...
  ...
```

settings.py

```
...
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'page': 'feincms_.migrate.page',
    'medialibrary': 'feincms_.migrate.medialibrary',
}
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Sites Framework: Initial Data Migration Location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127830/django-sites-framework-initial-data-migration-location)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, silly me. I needed a directory with an `__init__.py` for each module.

i.e.

```
- app
  - feincms_
    - migrate
      - __init__.py
      - page
        - __init__.py
      - medialibrary
        - __init__.py
    ...
  ...
```

So to sum this up, in order to set the location for any module's migrations in `Django`, you have to specify a valid python path in `MIGRATION_MODULES`. This path can be anywhere you like, but you have to make sure that it exists.